# How can I get notified with continous touch down events from my button instead only one?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiimageview

I must rotate an image but I can't use the gestures or the slider, so I have thinked about using 2 buttons, one for clockwise rotation and the other for couterclockwise rotation of my UIImageView.

But I'm getting notified only one  time for touch down event so my image rotate only one time.

There is a way to get continous touch down event when I press my button?

Is there isn't such opportunity, how can I implement this continous rotation with the two buttons?

Sorry if I've said something wrong I'm new to iOS development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of ways you could do this - UIButtons have `touchDown` and `touchUp` events, so you could start a process on `touchDown` and end it on `touchUpInside`.  [This discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284792/uibutton-touch-and-hold) might be useful.

Alternatively, rather than using UIbuttons you might want to try detecting a `touchesBegan` in a particular area (say on a UIImageView containing a button-lie image), then running the rotation animation until the `touchesEnded` event occurs?

Comment: Thank you very much, I've tried the method inside the discussion and it works out of the box!