# UIButton Press and Hold

Tags: ios, uibutton

I'd like to implement a press and hold button. So when you push the button, function A executes, and when you release, function B executes. I found this, but it wasn't what I was quite looking for.

[UIButton Touch and Hold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284792/uibutton-touch-and-hold)

I don't want any repeating action.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just add different selectors to the `UIButton` based on different events.  To set the selector for when you initially press down, do the following

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonDown:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

and the selector for when your button is released:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonUp:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: tried this, it seems that the button will release itself after about a second of being held down... do you know if this effect is an iOS7 specific problem?

Comment: This doesn't account for if the user touches up outside the area of the button. Whatever the `TouchDown` event is triggering when the button is held, will continue infinitely if the user touches up outside

Comment: I'm using this two events TouchDown and TouchUpInside  for "Before after button" and it works nice

Answer (score 20):

I have faced this problem myself, and mostly we use these events:-

```
// This event works fine and fires
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(holdDown)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

// This does not fire at all
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(holdRelease)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

**Solution:**

Use Long Press Gesture Recognizer:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *btn_LongPress_gesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] 
        initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleBtnLongPressGesture:)];
[button addGestureRecognizer:btn_LongPress_gesture];
```

Implementation of gesture:-

```
- (void)handleBtnLongPressGesture:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer { 

  //as you hold the button this would fire
  if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {   
    [self buttonDown];
  }

  // as you release the button this would fire
  if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    [self buttonUp];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can implement

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

method 
and then check if your button lies in the touch location using `CGRectContainsPoint()`

then if the user moves the finger

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

will be called..here you should again check if user is still on your button..otherwise stop your function

and

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

is called when user removes finger from the screen

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution for you would be to implement with UIGestureRecognizer, where one would be the UITapGestureRecognizer and the other a UILongPressGestureRecognizer

Answer (score 1):

UILongPressGestureRecognizer Swift 3 & above:

```
// Add Gesture Recognizer to view

let longPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(
            target: self,
            action: #selector(handleLongPress(_:)))

view.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGestureRecognizer!)
```