# Fast Rewind & Fast Forward in AVAudioPlayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am implementing AVAudioPlayer and fast-rewind,fast-forward functionality. I have made two button with gesture, images and glow effects. Currently when I tab on fast-forward, it initially forward the playing item to 10 sec and then playing same way as in normal, even though I am still pressing the button. I want to implement it exactly same like in Iphone/Ipod standard app.

Comment: did you make use of the AVAudioPlayer.currentTime property???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible solution is to implement the repeating action by an [`NSTimer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nstimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html). Have a look at [UIButton Touch and Hold](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3284792/1241690).

Answer (score 4):

You can use an `AVPlayer` instead and change the rate property on touch down.
Change it to -2 for rewind and 2 for fast-forward.
And remember to change the rate back to 1 on touch up inside/outside.

**EDIT** `AVPlayer`'s `rate` property supports values outside the `0.0`-`1.0`  range IF

> the associated player item returns YES for the AVPlayerItem properties canPlaySlowForward or canPlayFastForward

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1388846-rate

Comment: `AVPlayer`'s `rate` property only allows values from 0.5 for half speed playback to 2.0 for double speed playback. So your solution works perfect for fast forward but not for rewind. You have to use a `NSTimer` which sets the `currentTime` for rewind support.

Comment: @JenelEjercitoMyers Well it's simple. Instead of the `rate` property, which does not work for rewind, you just set the time of the track directly like so `[self.audioPlayer setCurrentTime:(self.audioPlayer.currentTime - 1.0f)];` If you want that the user can press the rewind button for a longer time and rewind constantly you just call the `setCurrentTime` again and again. One solution would be to start a `NSTimer` which does this as long as the user presses the rewind button like so `[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2 target:self selector:@selector(rewind:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];`