# Is there a way to rewind music using AVAudioPlayer?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, avaudioplayer

Im playing music using AVAudioPlayer and need help rewinding music. I got it to fast forward using `rate = 2.0`, but now Im not sure how to rewind the music using the rate property or something else. Can someone please help me figure this out. Thank you!

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)


        //this is for the left turntable
        if node.name == "lefttt" {

            //lets user rotate left turntable when there is one finger on turntable.
            let dy = leftTurntable.position.y - location.y
            let dx = leftTurntable.position.x - location.x
            let angle2 = atan2(dy, dx)
            leftTurntable.zRotation = angle2


            let delta = (angle2 - previousAngle)
            if delta > 0 {

                //rewind code
                print("rotateleft")
            }
            else {
                print("rotateright")

                musicPlayer.rate = 2
                musicPlayer.play()


            }
            previousAngle = angle2
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

AVAudioplayer does not provide any direct method to rewind the music.but you can set 'currentTime' property from the slider/button or any other way manually

From Apple doc:
[currentTime](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioPlayer/currentTime)

> By setting this property you can seek to a specific point in a sound
>   file or implement audio fast-forward and rewind functions.

Or if you want to use the rate property you may use `AVPlayer`. which supports rewind with rate also:
You can find more information about AVPlayer rewind here:https://stackoverflow.com/a/10761446/4557505

Comment: Yes but I'm gonna have to change a lot of my code to AVPlayer to get it to work. I tried using current time and it rewinds but I can't hear any sound when I rewind.