# iPhone SDK: UIButton repeat with repeat delay

Tags: iphone, uibutton, delay, repeat

I've implemented a repeated task on button (UIButton) hold with the code from another Stack Overflow thread ( [UIButton Touch and Hold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284792/uibutton-touch-and-hold) ).

For various reasons, I'd like a repeat delay. [definition of repeat delay](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_meant_by_'Repeat_Delay'_in_customizing_the_keyboard)

I can't quite wrap my head around how to do this however. I am relatively new to coding for the iPhone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired in the code you suggested you can go for something like this:

Make an `NSTimer` that will start up when the button is pressed and fire a method every `x` seconds.

Header (.h):

```
// Declare the timer and the needed IBActions in interface.
@interface className {
    NSTimer * timer;
}
-(IBAction)theTouchDown(id)sender;
-(IBAction)theTouchUpInside(id)sender;
-(IBAction)theTouchUpOutside(id)sender;

// Give the timer properties.
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer * timer;
```

Implementation file (.m):

```
// Synthesize the timer
// ...
```

Make an `IBAction` for "Touch Down" to start the timer that will fire the action method every 2 seconds.  Then make another IBAction for "Touch Up Inside" and "Touch Up Outside" to invalidate the timer.

For example:

```
-(IBAction)theTouchDown {

    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(action:)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                 repeats:NO];
}

-(IBAction)theTouchUpInside {

    [self.timer invalidate];
    self.timer = nil;
}

-(IBAction)theTouchUpOutside {

    [self.timer invalidate];
    self.timer = nil;
}
```

Then in that method fired by the `NSTimer` do whatever you need:

```
-(void)action:(id)sender {

    // ...
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you very much.

(If another novice programmer ends up reading this. It should be noted that you have to keep all the other code that was in the IBActions (theTouchUpOutside, theTouchUpInside, theTouchDown): e.g. the g=true/false from the link in the original question.)

Comment: OK i just realized it didn't fire once i just pushed it once quickly. So I performed the action once in the theTouchDown method and then allowed it to repeat afterwards with the rest of the code. Seems a little hack-ish but it works nicely.