# How to dynamically change UIButton title during Touch and Hold

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton

I am following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3284950/1506363) to change title of my UIButton. To sum up, here is what I have to do:

1. When user touches down, title of the button starts changing.
2. While touch is held, it should change every 1 second, and user
   should be able to see it.
3. When user touches up (stops touching), button title should be fixed to the last value held.

I handle 1 using [setTitle:forState:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006815-CH3-SW7)

I handle 2 using [setTitle:forState:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006815-CH3-SW7). This keeps happening as far as the timer keeps firing following user's touch, every 1 second.

I handle 3 using [titleForState](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006815-CH3-SW11). However here I don't get the value set in 2.
Sometimes when I get correct value, there is still one problem: After touch is over, I still see in UI the same old title on that custom UIButton, not the one that I read using titleForState. (for that matter, even UIButton.textLabel.text gives wrong value)

1 - Am I following the right approach for touch and hold? (I mean using the timer approach depicted to set and read UIButton titles)

2 - If yes, what should I change in my code to read correct UIButton title value?

EDIT:

I got rid of the issue I get in 3 above. The reason for the issue was: I wasn't supplying same `UIControlState` combination while reading and writing. I was assuming that if you supply `UIControlStateNormal | UIControlStateHighlighted` for writing title and then use `UIControlStateNormal` for reading it back, it should give back the currect title value, and vice versa. Unfortunately that's not the case. I changed my app logic so that I only have to use one of these states at both times.

However the main issue still remains (2 above) - how to show title while the UIButton is still in highlighted state. Title is completely invisible while the touch is held.

Comment: maybe try and change color title with `setTitleColor:forState:` ?

Comment: Tried but no success. Tried setting red color so it is visible anyway, but didn't see the change in UI.

Answer (score 1):

> how to show title while the UIButton is still in highlighted state. Title is completely invisible while the touch is held.

Is your button configured such that the title disappears during a touch event, without your code changing the title text? That is with no code changing the title does it still disappear?

I think your button needs to be redrawn, try calling `[button setNeedsDisplay]` after changing the title text.

Comment: I tried but no success yet. Additionally, also tried to set it in storyboard, but it stopped changing at all (pressed or non-pressed). Not sure what's the key to this, maybe I need to override UIbutton which is sort of overkill for the functionality I want to achieve.