# UILongPressGestureRecognizer work like delete button in iOS

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I have delete button that delete text.

I want to delete text continuously with `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` like iOS Built in keyboard delete button.

Here is my code

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *ges = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressGestureAction:)];
    ges.minimumPressDuration = 0.7;
    ges.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    ges.delegate = self;

    [self.deleteButton addGestureRecognizer:ges];

- (void)longPressGestureAction : (UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)lon
{
    [self deleteAction];
}
```

Above code is work only one time when i press long in Delete button and delete one letter.But it's not delete continuously.
However when i moving above Delete Button , it's working and delete continuously every letter.

But i don't want to moving above Delete button. I want to delete continuously pressing delete button without moving around.

How can i do it?

Comment: This might interest you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284792/uibutton-touch-and-hold